# Deactivate all Wordpress plugin updates

Tags: wordpress, plugins, updates

I have a question about my wordpress installation on my server. I now manage the site with git and just want to make updates on my local development version. How can I deactivate all plugin updates in wordpress so that they are no longer visible under updates in wp-admin dashboard.

Tank you :)

Comment: You can look into here, [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20580/disable-update-notification-for-individual-plugins)

Comment: Add  add_filter('site_transient_update_plugins', '__return_false'); in functions.php

Comment: You can also consider this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-wordpress-updates/

Comment: @user3040610 Thansk, worked for me :-)

Comment: @ItsOdi,glad it helped you.accept the comment if it works